# firebase auth is not a function()

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am following the following github to test authentication on firebase on node.js, https://github.com/hvalls/node-firebase-auth-example

I am getting the firebase.auth() is not a function.

I have tried the following:

1. Remove Firebase-admin
2. Remove Firebase
3. Reinstall Firebase via Npm

I just cant figure out whats wrong.

```
user_service.js

const firebaseapp = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/auth");

const apiKey = xxxx
const fb = firebaseapp.initializeApp({
  apiKey: apiKey,
});

exports.addUser = (email, password) =>
  fb.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

exports.authenticate = (email, password) =>{
    
    fb.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}
```

Route.js

```
router.post('/now', function (req, res, next){
  console.log('Here');
  try {
    const u =  userService.authenticate(req.body.email, req.body.password);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error : " + error);
    req.sendStatus(500).send(error);  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ideally use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) on server. The error you are getting might be because you've installed [Modular SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) (v9.0.0+) which does not use the name-spaced syntax. Try installing Admin SDK (`firebase-admin`) and refactoring the code as shown below:

```
router.post('/user', async function (req, res, next){
  try {
    const newUser = await userService.addUser(req.body.email, req.body.password);
    return res.json(newUser)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error : " + error);
    req.sendStatus(500).send(error);  
  }
});
```

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp({
  // service account
});

exports.addUser = async (email, password) => {
  return admin.auth().createUser({ email, password });
}
```

You cannot login user using Admin SDK (unless you are using session based auth) so after the user is created you should log the user in with `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` on your client application using client SDK.